# Regular expression to match *A* characters and optional ""

Tags: c#, regex

I need the string below is valid in regex.

```
string pattern = @"({[0-9]+}) (=|>|<|\*A*) ([a-z0-9]+)";
string input = "{123} = \"10\" || {12334} < 1000 || {8} > abcs || {34} *A* 33 || {22} *A* \"ábcd\"";

Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled);
MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(input);

if (matches.Count > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1} matches):", input, matches.Count);
    foreach (Match match in matches)
        Console.WriteLine("   " + match.Value);
}
else
    Console.WriteLine("Nothing" );
```

How do I make my regex work for all cases the string (input)?
The above code should return 5 matches.

Comment: You need to escape the * characters in the regex, otherwise they are treated as quantifiers.  Something like `\*`.

Comment: Accept some answers/finish off your previous questions. Also what are you trying to match?

Comment: you need to make it `string pattern = @"({[0-9]+}) (=|>|<|\*A\*) ([a-z0-9]+)";`

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand you.. but isn't this all you want? `[^|]+`.. that gets each group between `||`.. which is 5.

Comment: Hi all. Thanks. The @Sina Iravanian explained to me very well. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
(\{[0-9]+\})\s+(\=|\>|\<|\*A\*)\s+\"?([\p{L}\d]+)\"?
```

You needed to escape the second `*` too. Also your input string contains unicode letters which do not fall into `[a-z]` therefore I used `\p{L}` instead which matches all letters. Also you didn't account for optional quotes around letters, so I added two `\"?` around the right-hand-side of the expression. To store the above in an @-quoted string you need to do repeat double quotes twice, as in:

```
string pattern = @"(\{[0-9]+\})\s+(\=|\>|\<|\*A\*)\s+\""?([\p{L}\d]+)\""?";
```

I have a tendency to escape all the symbols while it might not be necessary.

Comment: +1, but you can get rid of most of those backslashes: `@"({[0-9]+})\s+([=><]|\*A\*)\s+""?([\p{L}\d]+)""?"`.

Comment: @AlanMoore Yes you're right. It's just an old habit. I'm happy that C# has @-quoted strings. Otherwise it would be very ugly.